# (Highcharts) Circle/wedge areas in polar chart

Tags: charts, highcharts, diagram

I need to draw some charts to describe area-effect patterns (gaming related stuff) that come in two varieties:

(1) Circular "splash" with 3-4 intensity radius values separated by color (say 1, 2, 3 in red, orange and yellow).

(2) Wedge with starting angle, ending angle and radius (say -30, +30 and 5).

I will pull the data from a bunch of existing data, examples below. But can I do this with Highcharts polar chart? Is there a good way to define areas like that? Can you make a range series to go around the polar axis for example? And how to make a proper wedge?

```
area_effect: {
| distance: {
| | short: 0f;
| | medium: 0.5f;
| | long: 1.2f;
| | distant: 1.2f;
| };
| area_info: {
| | angle_left: 0f;
| | angle_right: 0f;
| | radius: 1.2f;
| | area_type: "Circle";
| };
| hp_damage: {
| | short: 1f;
| | medium: 0.4f;
| | long: 0.2f;
| | distant: 0.2f;
| };
};

area_info: {
| angle_left: -70f;
| angle_right: 70f;
| radius: 5f;
| area_type: "Pie";
| line_length: 0f;
| radius_inner: 0f;
};
```