# (Highcharts) Polar wedge/floating pie segments

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to make a chart that shows the last 30 minutes of wind direction, with the most recent reading on top of the others. Each reading should be a 90-degree pie segment, centered on the wind angle, plotted on a 360-degree polar chart.

It should also be divided into 12 segments, labelled A to L, instead of 0-360. However the segments are just for show; I do not want to corral my data into them, like a normal wind rose or column chart.
I think this guy is also looking for similar functionality: [(Highcharts) Circle/wedge areas in polar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009577/highcharts-circle-wedge-areas-in-polar-chart)

I have an image here to show you what I'm trying to achieve; this is plotted in PHP: http://futurshox.net/tmp/wind-dial-demo.png
In this example image, older readings are successively more transparent as you go back in time, so the last few readings stand out. I'm not desperate for transparency, but colour control would be nice.

Here's another showing how far I've got...
http://futurshox.net/tmp/wind-dial-demo2.png
The best I can come up with is to use a scatter plot with larger dots for more recent readings, and place the older ones closer to the middle. I've got my 12 segments but can't figure out how to re-label them; if you even can.

Is any of this possible?
Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

To relabel use `xAxis.labels.formatter` and to set exact number of labels use `tickInterval`.